# ASIHTTPRequest POST for basecamp

Tags: ios, ipad, authentication, asihttprequest

Hi I am using ASIHTTPRequest POST for adding time entry on basecamp for logged in user.
But

`- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveResponseHeaders:(NSDictionary *)responseHeaders`

method of ASIHTTPRequest is getting called and in

```
- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
```

I am getting error as access denied.

I also need to send aunthentication token to basecamp URl please help me how to do this.

```
 NSString *postData=[NSString stringWithFormat:                                             @"<time-entry>\
                <person-id> 898989 </person-id>\
                <date>2011-04-07</date>\
                <hours>2:00</hours>\
                <description>test</description>\
                </time-entry>"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://test.basecamphq.com/projects/4644/time_entries.xml"];

        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
        [request appendPostData:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
        [request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/xml"];
        [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/xml"];
        [request authenticationNeeded];

        [request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
        [request startAsynchronous];
```

This is my code. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is the right API doc:

http://developer.37signals.com/basecamp/

Then basecamp using HTTP basic authentication, meaning you need to do this:

[request setAuthenticationScheme:(NSString *)kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeBasic];
   [request setUsername:yourApiToken];
   [request setPassword:@"X"];

Putting your API token where it says 'yourApiToken'.